# Can't get Visual C++ to generate the same code give by Ghidra

Tags: c++, ghidra, register

I'm using visual c++ to create a mock dll that I'm trying to reverse using Ghidra and I'm doing good progress so far, however I'm stuck in a function that ghidra gives me the following:

```
                         **************************************************************
                         *                          FUNCTION                          *
                         **************************************************************
                         undefined __register FUN_00417344(undefined param_1, undefined 
         undefined         AL:1           <RETURN>
         undefined         AL:1           param_1
         undefined         DL:1           param_2
         undefined         CL:1           param_3
         undefined4        Stack[0x4]:4   param_4
```

I can't get visual c++ to compile the same thing, everything I try gives me:

```
                     **************************************************************
                     *                          FUNCTION                          *
                     **************************************************************
                     char __cdecl FUN_00417344(int * param_1, int * param_2, int * p
     char              AL:1           <RETURN>
     int *             Stack[0x4]:4   param_1                                 
     int *             Stack[0x8]:4   param_2
     int *             Stack[0xc]:4   param_3
     int *             Stack[0x10]:4  param_4
```

the function above is the result of:

```
__declspec(dllexport) char FUN_00417344(int* a, int* b, int* c, int* d)
{
    ...
}
```

How can I get VS to generate the parameters as AL, DL, CL etc...?

Comment: You'll probably want to look into calling conventions. I don't think cdecl uses registers at all.

Comment: IIRC the only calling conventions to use registers are `__fastcall` and `__thiscall`, using ECX/EDX and ECX respectively. If your DLL isn't 32 bit, a different calling convention may be used. If the DLL is old, it might have been written in assembly, in which case some manual fiddling may be required

Comment: On a different note, AL/DL/CL are all 1 byte values (which ghidra usually labels as `undefined`). Pointers (in a 32 bit DLL) are 4 bytes wide and are therefore labelled as `undefined4`.